# How to use DataReader from Oledb and get results in Richtextbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, richtextbox, datareader, executereader

```
Dim srch As String
        srch = ccode.Text
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "\ptdr.accdb"
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim dsrch As New OleDbCommand("SELECT pname, page, vdate, psex, summer, bldp, blds, photh, diag, rl, trtmnt, nvdate FROM ptnt_data WHERE pcode = " & srch & "", conn)
        Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = dsrch.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dg As String = ""

            'diagnosis'
            dg = rdr.GetString(8).ToString()
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dg) Then
                diag1.Text = ""
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dg) Then
                diag1.Text = ""
            Else
                diag1.Text = dg

            End If
```

It works fine but when I search for a null it gives an error.
It says that I've an error at the line of

```
dg = rdr.GetString(8).Tostring()
```

any suggests?

Comment: Also you probably need to look at IDisposable / Using statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rdr.GetString(8).ToString()
```

if `rdr.GetString(8`) is null this is a classic null reference exception

`rdr.GetString(8)` IS a string so just remove the `.ToString()`

As per my comment below you can only run GetString if the DB has an underlying type of string for this data, what is the datatype of column diag?

(ie run rdr.GetFieldType(8) in the debugger and provide the type name)

As you have confirmed this *is* a string type and the issue is just with null handling (sorry i didn;t spot that from your question) you need:

```
If rdr.IsDBNull(8) Then diag1.Text = "" Else diag1.Text = rdr.GetString(8) EndIf
```

Which should replace everything from Dim dg... down

Comment: Specified cast is not valid. => where?

Comment: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "No conversions are performed; therefore the data retrieved must already be a string." will update answer

Comment: dg = rdr.GetString(8)
this line

Comment: should i try this instead ?
     'diagnosis'
            If IsDBNull(rdr.GetString(8)) Then
                dg = "empty"
            Else
                dg = rdr.GetString(8)
            End If

Comment: datatype OleDbType.WChar

Comment: still the same problem :\

Comment: According to this WChar should map to string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, ++ see updated answer

Comment: Error 1 Value of type 'System.Type' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: and where is that?   have you removed the  rdr.GetFieldType(8)  stuff?

Comment: if your still having issues post as an update the new, full, code